# bash command for moving all subdirectories less than a certain size

Tags: bash

I'm using

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./mvsmalldirs.sh {} \;
```

to pass each subdirectory in Movies to this shell script:

```
SIZE=$(du -sb "$1" | cut -f1)
if [[ $SIZE -lt 5000000 ]]; then
    mv -t "$1" ../Moved/
    read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"
fi
```

At first I was having problems with spaces in the directory name but now that I've (I think) figured that out, something else really weird is happening... as soon as I run the find command, the script deletes the destination directory. If I'm barking up the wrong tree, could someone please tell me the right way to move all directories with a size of less than 5MB?

Answer (score 1):

This command is guilty:

```
mv -t "$1" ../Moved/
```

The *-t* option must be followed by the target directory, which is `../Moved` in your case, and not `"$1"` which is the source, as far as I understand. I suppose you mean:

```
mv -t ../Moved/ "$1"
```

Comment: O yes, and you will find your (empty) `Moved` directory back inside of the first small directory you tried to move.